# Meta tags react js

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags

I'm having a little problem.

My web-app is written in **react js** (client-side) and **express js** (server side).

I searched alot about the **meta-tags**, and how it works in **react**. Website like **Facebook, Twitter** and so on take the metatags that are in the original document and not the metatags created by js.

Now I founded this library: **https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet** . It is very useful, but I'm not understanding where I am wrong.

I've a component, I load informations in **componentWillMount()** function, and then in my **render()** function I've this:

```
{!this.state.loading && this.state.user !== null && // setto i metatags
   <Helmet>
       <title>{this.state.user.username}</title>
       <meta property="og:title" content={this.state.user.biography}></meta>
   </Helmet>
}
```

It works, I've my **username in title**, and **the description as I want**.

[image]

But when I copy my link to Facebook, I **saw the original title and description** **that are on the index.html file**. If I delete the  and other meta-tags from index.html, I've an empty "preview url".

**How could I solve?**

Comment: Your React app is first rendered when the JavaScript has been loaded. Facebook, Twitter, etc. doesn't run you JavaScript, so Helmet will never render, and your meta tags will not be set. You could use something like [Razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle) to do the initial render on the server side, and it will work as you expect.

Comment: so I can solve only with a server-side-rendering?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I was reading this interesting [article](https://itnext.io/pre-rendering-your-react-application-with-react-snap-234e2408ed39). Does it work? Is it another solution?

Comment: Yes, that could be a nice solution as well! It will crawl your site and press all the links it can find, so granted that you have links for all your pages it might just be what you need.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't a solution for me. My problem is that I'm running an express server for the API request. It runs on port 2053, my website (client side) on 80. I don't know how to do an ssr, and I can't find out some code-example/tutorial